# Regular expression: find range except for one letter or a range

Tags: php, regex

How can I use the negation within square brackets as an exception, to find e. g. everything between a-z except for the the range from m-o? `[a-z^m-o]`?

By the way: it's not for the sake of this example that I ask, but to be able to exclude ranges within ranges, or even single letters within ranges. I am pretty much aware that in this example it can be calculated.

I use the Zend engine (PHP).

Comment: trivial solution would be `[a-mo-z]`

Comment: Both of those comments are incorrect, guys.

Comment: @Pointy: Either that or the question is incorrect. See the title.

Comment: He says "except for a range", so that means "except for the range 'm' through 'o'" in his example. The comment from @gt is wrong because it's just a syntax error (in any regex syntax I'm familiar with), and @Drakosha's answer is wrong because his will match 'm' and 'o'.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able calculate the difference yourself.

```
[a-lp-z]
```

If the regex engine supports lookahead assertion, you could use

```
(?![m-o])[a-z]
```

but this would probably be less efficient.

Comment: Note that the regex should be grouped "(?:(?![m-o])[z-z])+" as @Wiktor Stribiżew commented to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41097232/3552975)(at least in Python).

Comment: The point of grouping the lookahead with the pattern being restricted is that a quantifier placed after the character class will only pertain to this class, and not the lookahead. In that case, e.g. `(?!n)[a-z]+`, only the first letter will be restricted, i.e. it will match `mnnnn`, but not `nmmmm`. When grouped, the each of the characters matched will be restricted.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to what Kenny mentions:

1. [The JDK](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (at least) supports this syntax:

   [a-z&&[^m-o]]
2. [A couple](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xmlcharclass.html) of engines (including the .NET framework) support this:

   [a-z-[m-o]]

Comment: very informatiove, however, neither of these works with PHP. :(

Comment: Im using Python... any good alternatives to the above patterns?

Comment: @Justin: the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package supports similar syntax, e.g., `[a-z--[m-o]]`, or else just go with the accepted answer, which works with pretty much any regex engine.