# Require letter in [A-Z] set

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to match number plates in a database using REGEX so I can set them a type, so I don't have to use REGEX in any future queries.

I've got two expressions that match dateless / irish plates. I need to separate irish plates from dateless plates.

Irish plates must include the letter I or Z, dateless plates cannot include I or Z.

These are the two expressions that match both dateless and irish.

```
REGEXP '^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,4}$'
REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]{1,3}$'
```

The problem I have is excluding the I-Z, I can do [A-HJ-Y], but this will result in crossovers.

How can I modify the expressions above to require I and Z, and then another set of expressions to exclude I and Z.

Many Thanks

Comment: can you clarify how will `[A-HJ-Y]` result in crossovers?

Comment: If I have these two expressions for irish plates (must include I and Z):

`REGEXP '^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,4}$'`
`REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]{1,3}$'`

And then replace [A-Z] with [A-HJ-Y] for datepless plates (no I or Z), if a plate is MFF 500, both sets of expressions will match.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363722/regular-expression-find-range-except-for-one-letter-or-a-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irish plates are either:

- `^([IZ][A-Z]{0,2}|[A-Z]([IZ][A-Z]?|[A-Z][IZ]))[0-9]{1,4}$`
- `^[0-9]{1,4}([IZ][A-Z]{0,2}|[A-Z]([IZ][A-Z]?|[A-Z][IZ]))$`

If you're prepared to tolerate up to 5 letters, these can be simplified to:

- `^[A-Z]{0,2}[IZ][A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{1,4}$`
- `^[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]{0,2}[IZ][A-Z]{0,2}$`

Dateless plates are either:

- `^[A-HJ-Y]{1,3}[0-9]{1,4}$`
- `^[0-9]{1,4}[A-HJ-Y]{1,3}$`

Comment: The regex for irish plates doesn't match plates such as JNZ 4. I'm rubbish with REGEX but I'm guessing that the regex posted for irish plates only works where I or Z is in the middle?

Comment: @RyanPilbeam: It should match... see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/11243/0).