# Match two distinct letters

Tags: c#, regex

Valid input is any two uppercase letters but they cannot be the same letter.  I thought the following would work by subtracting the first matched group (the first letter) from the character class for the second letter.

```
Regex ValidInput = new Regex(@"^([A-Z])[A-Z-[\1]]$");

ValidInput.IsMatch("AA"); // should be false but is true
```

Why is this wrong and what's the correct way to do it?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3363740/4960774)

```
([A-Z])(?!\1)[A-Z]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex

```
^(?:([A-Z])(?!.*\1)){2}$
```

Answer (score 1):

I like regex and all but I think this is more readable:

```
var valid = yourString.length == 2
  && char.IsUpper(yourString[0])
  && char.IsUpper(yourString[1])
  && yourString[0] != yourString[1];
```

If you have trouble getting regex to work, how long is it going to take for someone to figure out what you're trying to accomplish with the regex when they review your code?

Comment: You make a good point, but this is a simplified example that is really just going to be a component of a much larger regex.

Comment: Also hopefully he comments well so when someone looks through his code they won't have to figure out anything, just read the comment telling them what it does.

Comment: But isn't that why they say comments are evil?  Sometimes they lie.  :-)  But yes, I agree with you.  Regular expressions are definitely an exception for the great comment debaters to consider.

Comment: Haha Yes it is true. But I don't trust others code anyway so it is more for my benefit than for anything.