# regex: a range but exclude a few items?

Tags: python, regex, vim

Suppose that I want to match a range of characters, a toy example `[0-9]`, but except a few, say `3` and `6`.

There are several ways to tackle this:

1. list them

---

```
a = 'a certain string'    
the_range_list = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']   
the_outliers_list = ['3', '6']    
matched = re.search("[%s]" % "".join(list(set(the_range_list)-set(the_outliers_list))), a)
```

---

2. several ranges

   `[0-24-57-9]`
3. the existing answer

---

```
a = '23491782634798169'      
r = '(?![36])[0-9]+'    
re.findall(r, a)
```

---

What I expected to get is ["2", "491782", "", "47981", "9"], but what I get is ['23491782634798169'].

My question is that if the range is rather big say all CJK characters and the exception is a continuous(in the Unicode table) or discrete list, how can I use regex to represent such a range? And any implementations for that in Vim or/and Python?

Hope that this is not duplicated.

Comment: You may use a negative lookahead to restrict a character class in both Python and Vim (the notation is different though).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  The question is what I missed before raising this question but the answer may be not. I mean the answer seems don't work(I saw such methods elsewhere) as I updated in my question.

Comment: No, the answer for Item 3 is `r = '(?:(?![36])[0-9])+'`. You *must group* the lookahead with the pattern under restriction.

Comment: Well, I am no longer sure it is a dupe. Let's see if there are any reopen votes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the dupe is fine, but the answer in this question should be adjusted for repetition (or a new one added for this case)

Comment: I agree with you. Thanks.